# Clone git repo via https without entering the password manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, chef, opsworks

I've got a stack in Amazon OpsWorks and within this stack I got a RailsApp Layer. The repository is only accessible via https and is protected with username and password. On my machine I can clone the repo via:

`git clone https://username:password@XXX.com/repo.git`

OpsWorks complains that the URL is invalid because of the `:`

Is there a way to set the password explicitly before chef tries to clone the repo?
All the articles I red just describe how to cache credentials but they have to be typed in manually the first time. I look for a way to fully automate this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using a `.netrc` file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to manually clone the repo? Then a `.netrc` file is a fine answer.

The OpsWorks recipes accomplish this during the *deploy* event by setting up a custom `.netrc` file for the deploy user. Instead of cloning the repo manually, you can run the OpsWorks *deploy* event either from the OpsWorks UI, or manually on the instance (after you have run it at least once from the UI) with the `opsworks-agent-cli` command:

`sudo opsworks-agent-cli run_command deploy`

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure an SSH key then do a git clone through SSH:

```
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:MyPathTo/MyRepo.git --branch 1.x --single-branch /var/www/temp
```